# Docpad: get collection item dynamically

Tags: docpad, eco

I am new to [docpad](http://docpad.org).
I have something like filter in my project. There is few switchers to filter a list of icons. After user clicks an icon, the details about chosen item should be shown.  This item is in docpad collection. How to implement this? 
Every icon in the list has the id which is equal to the id of responding item in docpad collection.
Is there any way to store id of chosen item in a variable `onclick`(in order to use it in filter of `getCollection` or `getFileById` in eco template)?

Comment: DocPad after generation doesn't have getCollection or getFileById method, it generates static content and trying to force reactivity server-side doesn't seem to be good idea. Maybe store your files under /files/{{id}} and create json list of those files that you will use to sort them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unclear about what you want to achieve. If you want to filter items on a page with a user click, something like a masonry/pinterest layout, then the way is to output all collection items to the page and then filter them with client side JavaScript. If you want to display further details when a user clicks on an item, the principle is the same. Output all details of the collection to the page but only make the full details visible when an item is clicked on by the user (again using client side script).

Now, if the collection is too large or it's contents too long to output to a page and you need to generate content on post back (ie dynamically) then a page can be marked `dynamic = true` in the metadata. And you will also need to install the [clean urls plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docpad-plugin-cleanurls)

Edit:

As an example of filtering a collection on a dynamically generated page using the eco template system.

```
---
layout: simple
dynamic: true
---

<%collection = ['Aardvark',"Arrows","Armageddon","Buildings","Bats","Bob the builder"] %>
<%query = @req.query%>
<%-query.q%>
<%filter = query.q%>
<h1><%-(new Date()).toString()%></h1>
<ul>
<% for item in collection:%>
<%if item[0].toLowerCase() == filter or !filter:%>
    <li><%-item%></li>
<%end%>
<%end%>
</ul>
```

This assumes that there is a query parameter in the form of `q=a`or `q=b`etc. ie `http://127.0.0.1:9778/?q=a`. I've also written out the date to prove that the page is regenerated on each request.

Checkout the [metadata section](http://docpad.org/docs/meta-data/) of the DocPad documentation.

Comment: I have the same problem: Users need to be able to filter a list. Looks like you do give hints how to solve this but they are too general for me to understand. Could you link to docs or examples on dynamic page creation please?

Comment: Thank for your answer. Please, take a look at  this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B9Hnu/137/) to see what I want to achieve. It's just simple example

Comment: Now I have some solution. Whole collection loads at once. But only the first item's details stay visible, all the others are hidden. But it causes long time of page loading(